# Cordova camera saves to gallery even on false

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm in a really nasty situation...

My client wants a Cordova application in Ionic Framework v1, and it's imperative that the camera does not save images to gallery. However, when I set the parameter for saving to gallery to false, it is still saving to gallery.

The problem occurs on Android when you take a photo and cancel it. It then saves that picture to gallery and sometimes even saves all other pictures after that.

I would really welcome any kind of help; All I've found so far are some solutions that I find really hard to understand since my knowledge of Java is zero.

Here is my JS code

```
function capturePhoto() {
    var maxDimension = 1280;
    var options = {
      quality: 80,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      correctOrientation: true,
      targetWidth: maxDimension,
      targetHeight: maxDimension,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false

    };
```

This is for camera options.

```
 $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
      var src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      $scope.photoPreviewSrc = src;
    }).catch(function (err) {

    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm confused - where does Java come into this if you're doing a Cordova app?

Comment: Well plugin is written in java for android...so maybe someone with java knowledge already had something with this problem..

Comment: I have verified the same, but it works as expected. I had set saveToGallery flag to true. If I cancel, image is not saved. When I clicked on ok, image is saved to gallery.

Comment: @bvakiti and what when you set saveToGallery to false and then u capture photo and cancel it?

Comment: Can you show the code that you used. Can you be more specify about the issue

Comment: i updated my question with js code

Answer (score 2):

I have checked with your code using cordova. It works fine as expected. 
Verify your app in other device once.

I haven't checked it on ionic platform.

Comment: When you set savetogallery to false and cancel picture after taking it,you dont get it saved to gallery?

Comment: No. When you cancel, it again shows the camera for capture. Image is not saved in gallery. Verify it once in other device

Comment: I verified normal cordova app, it works as expected, with the same code

Comment: @bvakiti that tells me that the problem lies in ionic platform.  Go ahead and edit your question to clarify this.

Comment: just tried with regular cordova code navigator.camera.getPicture insted of $cordovaCamera.getPicture...still getting same problem.. i will try to check with other version and update it here then...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try running something like the following after you receive the image data:

```
navigator.camera.cleanup(onSuccess, onFail);

function onSuccess() {
    console.log("Camera cleanup success.")
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

From [the docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameracleanup): "`camera.cleanup()` Removes intermediate image files that are kept in temporary storage after calling `camera.getPicture`. Applies only when the value of `Camera.sourceType` equals `Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA` and the `Camera.destinationType` equals `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`."

The above relates directly to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really going to the photo gallery, or just showing up in Android's photo app? The Android default photo browser will show all photos, screenshots, etc. It will also even show just random images - that other Apps may have on the file system, but that aren't photos.

Since in cordova, you don't have great control of the OS, you can use a work around: You can place the images in a hidden directory (starting with a `.` such `.appdata`) and this will prevent Android from automatically seeing the images from the "Gallery" app. I had this problem in an Ionic App and solved it that way.

Comment: He is putting images to storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera . How did you manage this solution with changing image path,can you give me hint?

Comment: If you want to hide them you can put them in /storage/emulated/sdcard/.mdir or something like this